# SQL Multi-condition WHERE clause with one optional parameter?

Tags: sql-server

Reworking an existing Stored Procedure to make a previously required parameter optional.

The query is massive, and deals with much more than my current issue, so I won't post it in it's entirety but I believe I can get my fix by editing one of the `WHERE` clauses.

```
WHERE
        O.wsID = @wsid AND 
        ((M.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate) OR (MI.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate))
```

The first parameter `@wsid` is the value I need to make optional, it's initially declared as 0 and given a new value from a select box on the front-end of the website. I have attempted to use a `CASE` statement to alternate between to `WHERE` clauses depending on whether the value is 0 or an actual ID.

```
WHERE
        @wsid = CASE
                WHEN @wsid <> 0 THEN ((O.wsID = @wsid) AND ((M.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate) OR (MI.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate)))
                ELSE ((M.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate) OR (MI.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate)))
                END
```

But I get a bunch of syntax errors in the `WHERE` clause itself and also an error stating `Expecting CONVERSATION or TRY` for the `SELECT` statement below.

Is there an easier option for making the `O.wsid = @wsid` parameter optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE
        (O.wsID = @wsid OR @wsid = 0) AND 
        ((M.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate) OR (MI.UpdateDate BETWEEN @olddate AND @newdate))
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple... ah well, that's Monday morning for you. Thanks, works perfectly.

Comment: Just be careful, "OR @wsid = 0" may cause a table scan. OPTION (RECOMPILE) prevents this from happening.

Comment: @under yes, you are right. It can be painfull sometimes